# Store specific interactions with Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite, core-data

I was reading the docs on core data looking to speed up my search. I found the following and was slightly confused as to what it meant:

> The SQL store, on the other hand,
>   compiles the predicate and sort
>   descriptors to SQL and evaluates the
>   result in the database itself. This is
>   done primarily for
>   performance—databases are much faster
>   at this (it's what they're designed
>   for)—but it means that evaluation
>   happens in a non-Cocoa environment,
>   and so sort descriptors (or
>   predicates) that rely on Cocoa cannot
>   work. The supported sort selectors are
>   compare: and caseInsensitiveCompare:.
>   Note that in addition you cannot sort
>   on transient properties using the
>   SQLite store.

[the documentation is here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875)

Does this mean that they recommend that one not use predicates or sort descriptors when fetching managed objects from an sqlite store?

I currently have a FetchRequest where I pass the following:

```
    NSPredicate *thingSearchPredicate = 
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"label BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", searchText];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = 
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"label" ascending:YES];
```

The search works but I think I am using a predicate that relies on cocoa. BEGINSWITH is I assume a compare:options:range: shorthand where range is search string length. The fact that is is diacritic insensitive definitely seems to countermand the advice above so does that just mean that they are evaluated automatically for me after all instances of that entity have been fetched?

Are there any other ways to speed up search?

Comment: No, they *don't* mean you can't use predicates or sort descriptors w/ the NSSQLiteStore... just that *certain* predicates and sort descriptors that might work for another store don't work with the SQLLite store.

Basically, they have to be able to compile them down to a SQL statement. BEGINSWITH[cd] can easily be expressed in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will see an error if core data can't express your query in SQL.  The documentation specifies that the expressions are taken and converted into SQL and passed to sqllite for performance reasons.  Not that it will degenerate to Cocoa if it can't be expressed in SQL.

What they are meaning is there certainly *are* predicates not expressible in SQL so will not work at all.

Additionally, you need to use their sort selectors and you can't make your own, because they don't know how to covert arbitrary objects in Cocoa to SQL.